# Android getting data from joined tables

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a problem of how to retrieve some data from two tables.

I have tables Movie and Category and they look like this with MOVIE being FK on MOVIEID:

```
Movie
-----
_ID TITLE   MOVIEID
-----------------
1   BATMAN    123
2   TWILIGHT  234
3   IRONMAN   345

Category
--------
_ID  TITLE   MOVIE
------------------
1    SCI-FI   123
2    ACTION   123
3    CRIME    123
4    ROMANCE  234
5    SCI-FI   234
6    SCI-FI   345
7    ACTION   345
```

From this I want to get movies that are both SCI-FI and ACTION for example. After I join the tables on MOVIEID = MOVIE:

```
BATMAN  SCI-FI
BATMAN  ACTION
BATMAN  CRIME
TWILIGHT ROMANCE
TWILIGHT SCI-FI
IRONMAN SCI-FI
IRONMAN ACTION
```

How do I get DISTINCT titles only from movies that are both SCI-FI and ACTION(i.e. BATMAN AND IRONMAN) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a `COUNT` aggregate and the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT M.MovieId, M.Title
FROM Movie M
    JOIN Category C ON M.MovieId = C.Movie
WHERE C.Title IN ('SCI-FI','ACTION')
GROUP BY M.MovieId, M.Title
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C.Title) = 2
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2cec7/1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Had to hack Android API a little to get it working but yea it works :).

Comment: Downvoted in error, unable to recind.  The answer is appropriate and spot-on as given.